# Jquery if contenteditable=true event

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Im trying to detect if the element I have clicked on is contentEditable. I have tried this:

```
$( "#thediv" ).hide();    
$(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).is("[contenteditable='true']")) {
    return true;
    $( "#thediv" ).show();
    alert('hi');
} else if ($(this).is("[contenteditable='false']")) {
    return false;
    $( "#thediv" ).hide();
    alert('hi');            
}
});
```

AND

```
$( "#thediv" ).hide();  

$(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("contentEditable") == true) {  
        $( "#thediv" ).show();
        alert('yes');
    } else {
        $( "#thediv" ).hide();  
        alert('no');          
    }    
});
```

How can I get this to work?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRLh7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not defined. Here Ya go 
http://jsfiddle.net/dqEE2/2/

```
$( "#hello" ).hide();  
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("contentEditable") == "true") {
            $( "#hello" ).show();
            alert("yes");
        } else {
            alert("no");
          $( "#hello" ).hide(); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

The `contenteditable` attribute will tell you whether the element has an explicit value set for contenteditable. However, editability is inherited, so an element such as the `<span>` in the HTML below is editable but has no `contenteditable` attribute value:

```
<div contenteditable="true"><span>Some editable text</span></div>
```

What you need instead is the [`isContentEditable` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.isContentEditable), which does exactly what you want:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    if (this.isContentEditable) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using jQuery's attr? http://api.jquery.com/attr/
That might work

```
if ($(this).attr("contentEditable") == "true") {
```

EDIT: the following works just fine:

```
if ($(this).is("[contentEditable='true']")) {
```

afro360's problem was something different

Comment: @afro360 I changed `true` to `"true"` and it works now (for me).

Comment: You're only adding the event to the hidden element. How am I supposed to click that? Look at this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqEE2/)

Comment: In my fiddle when I click on the contenteditable I want to show the #hello. If the div you click on is not contenteditable I want it to hide the #hello.

Comment: It hides if I remove the 1st $( "#hello" ).hide(); but does not show when I click the contenteditable.

Comment: Then replace the `$(this).click(function() ...`, which adds the click event listener to the hidden event to something like `$("#test").click(function() ...`

Answer (score 0):

To use the *element.isContentEditable*  will be the simplest solution.

```
$(".edit").on("click", function() {
  var status = document.getElementById("theContent").isContentEditable;
  $("#theContent").prop("contenteditable", !status);
});
```